# @Configuration class provides beans of a given qualifier but never of other

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have two configuration classes like below

```
@Configuration
public class EnvConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public RAMTaskDAO   ramTaskDAO;

    @Autowired
    public MongoTaskDAO mongoTaskDAO;

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("ram")
    public TaskDAO ramTaskDAO() {
        return ramTaskDAO;
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("mongo")
    public TaskDAO mongoTaskDAO() {
        return mongoTaskDAO;
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class DevEnvConfiguration extends EnvConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @Qualifier("taskDao")
  public TaskDAO taskDAO() {
    return ramTaskDAO;
  }

}
```

---

My main class looks like below:

```
@Component
public class TaskDAOUsageDemonstrator {

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("taskDao")
  public TaskDAO taskDao;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("ram")
  public TaskDAO ramTaskDao;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("mongo")
  public TaskDAO mongoTaskDao;

  @ForSpring
  private TaskDAOUsageDemonstrator() {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericXmlApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("dev");
    context.load("applicationContext.xml");
    context.refresh();
  }
```

---

**Issue:**

When Spring tries to instantiate TaskDAOUsageDemonstrator, it is unable to find a TaskDAO of qualifier "mongo" for some reason. I am able to get Bean with other two qualifiers but not just with "mongo". I tried to rename the qualifier name to mongo1, but things didnt change.

**UPDATE**
I tried to return mongoTaskDao in DevEnvConfiguration, instead of ramTaskDAO, for the qualifier 'taskDao', and I was able to get a mongoTaskDao bean. For some reason, Type:TaskDAO with qualifier "mongo" only causes problem.

**Exception trace:**

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'taskDAOUsageDemonstrator': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.mb.taskmanager.TaskDAO com.mb.taskmanager.TaskDAOUsageDemonstrator.mongoTaskDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.mb.taskmanager.TaskDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=mongo)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:270)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1113)
    at com.mb.taskmanager.TaskDAOUsageDemonstrator.demoRamTaskDaoAutowired(TaskDAOUsageDemonstrator.java:84)
    at com.mb.taskmanager.TaskDAOUsageDemonstrator.main(TaskDAOUsageDemonstrator.java:53)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public com.mb.taskmanager.TaskDAO com.mb.taskmanager.TaskDAOUsageDemonstrator.mongoTaskDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.mb.taskmanager.TaskDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=mongo)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.mb.taskmanager.TaskDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=mongo)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:947)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:485)
    ... 13 more
```

Not to mention RAMTaskDAO and MongoTaskDAO exactly look alike:

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class RAMTaskDAO implements TaskDAO {

  private ConcurrentHashMap<String, BackendTask> taskMap;

  public RAMTaskDAO() {
    taskMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, BackendTask>();
  }

  ...
}

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class MongoTaskDAO implements TaskDAO {

  @Autowired
  public MongoOperations mongoOperations;

  public MongoTaskDAO() {
  }

  ...
}
```

**UPDATE: 
 applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit.xsd">

    <import resource="common-spring.xml" />
    <import resource="mongo-spring.xml" />
    <import resource="rabbit-spring.xml" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="test/app.properties" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mb" />
    <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

---

**mongo-spring.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="prod/app.properties" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mb.taskmanager.db" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <mongo:mongo host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="${mongo.dbname}" mongo-ref="mongo"
        username="${mongo.user}" password="${mongo.pwd}" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**app.properties**

```
mongo.host=myhost.com
mongo.port=27017
mongo.dbname=framework-unittesting-db
mongo.user=xxxxxxx
mongo.pwd=xxxxx

rabbit.host=localhost
rabbit.user=xxxx
rabbit.pwd=xxxxxxxxxx
```

**TaskManager** 
 
TaskManager  begins like this

```
public class TaskManager {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("taskDao")
  protected TaskDAO         taskDAO;

  @Autowired
  private TaskBrokerFactory taskBrokerFactory;

  private TaskManager() {
  }

  ....
```

}

Comment: First, why are you *extending* the `@Configuration` class instead of just loading them both independently?

Comment: Which is as expected. You are setting the active profile to dev, whereas the other beans are active in the default profile (which isn't active anymore). Instead of `setActiveProfiles` use `addActiveProfile`.

Comment: @M.Deinum (1) If setActiveProfiles() had made default profile inactive, then `@Autowired  @Qualifier("ram")  public TaskDAO ramTaskDao;` should also have failed to found a bean.                     (2) I tried to replace setActiveProfiles() with addActiveProfile(). I still see the issue

Comment: The order in which `@Autowired` is processed doesn't have to be the same each time and as the `ApplicationContext` fails fast it basically stops everything at the first error. Can you add your `applicationContext.xml`, is there a reason why you still have an xml an not using an `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` instead?

Comment: Please post your xml.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the explanation. Can I understand how XML can impact here? Can I conclude that having to look into XML inherently means, the configuration code was not sufficient for Spring to pick a TaskDAO of qualifier "mongo". As per examples I read the configuration java code was all that was required. And it works if I just comment out `@Autowired @Qualifier("mongo") public TaskDAO mongoTaskDao;`. I am beginning with spring, so some of my assumptions may be wrong. Correct me!

Comment: Your configuration is weird. Why the java-config and verbose xml?! I would stick with either xml or javaconfig but not both (especially not when you are just starting). You have a lot of duplication and a lot of duplication in your component-scanning. Judging by the error I guess your @Configuration classes aren't picked up and only the xml and defaults are used (I.e. the things picked up with component scanning).

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want, because with all the code and configuration it is unclear. Why the `@Configuration` class and xml? I would suggest to start with xml only (you can still use the profiles). Is it possible you put your project somewhere?

Comment: @M.Deinum I understand the duplication. Agreed. Will fix it.                              But error happens only when `@Autowired @Qualifier("mongo") public TaskDAO ramTaskDao;` but not with`@Autowired @Qualifier("ram") public TaskDAO ramTaskDao;' And none of their spring configuration is in XML. All in java-config. As mentioned previously, if I comment out `@Autowired @Qualifier("mongo") public TaskDAO ramTaskDao;` everything works smoothly proves that 'ram' and 'taskDao' both have no problems.

Comment: The problem is there is so much going on in your current setup it is hard to tell. There are duplicated bean instances, duplicated names and you aren't even posting your `common-spring.xml` and `rabbit-spring.xml`. You are using component-scanning however there is no way to see if the `@Configuration` class is actually even being used. Regarding ` none of their spring configuration is in XML` actually they are due to the `<context:component-scan />` and `@Component` annotation on the respective classes.

Comment: @M.Deinum Unfortunately I cannot share the code fully. I tried to make up an example myself to simulate my scenario. I was able to reproduce the issue. Pls see: https://github.com/seshumadhav/java-projects/tree/master/spring-profiles. Can PTAL

Comment: @M.Deinum Error I get on running the [ProfileDemo-github project] (https://github.com/seshumadhav/java-projects/blob/master/spring-profiles/src/com/spring/profiles/ProfileDemo.java): Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.spring.profiles.Service] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=serviceImpl)}

Comment: Either yuor sample is wrong or the code you posted isn't like the code in your Sample. Your Sample is missing `@Bean` annotations so no beans (apart from the `@Component` beans) are there and basically injection of ALL fields fail. Simply add `@Bean` and it works like a charm on my machine.

Comment: @M.Deinum Oops forgot to add `@Bean`. But yes, the sample code works.   AFAIK, this dummy code base is modeled same as my original code. Now,I have to dig through my code-base(that is causing issues), do some cleanup first, then retry.

Comment: Another thing to check in your actual code is that you use the correct `@Qualifier` annotation (the spring one not the one from CDI).

Comment: @M.Deinum I am not sure why/how this thing worked: But Instead of `@Bean @Qualifier("ram") public TaskDAO ramTaskDAO()`, I tried `@Bean(name = "ram") public TaskDAO ramTaskDAO()` (did same for mongo as well). And the whole thing started working well. Didnot have to change any other configuration at all. Weird! Thanks for the  support guys.